# Can you source a "here document"?

Tags: bash, shell, here-document

Let's say I have a bash script that acts as a config file for another bash script:

config.sh:

```
verbose=yes
echo "Malicious code!"
name=test
```

script.sh:

```
source config.sh
echo "After sourcing: verbose='$verbose', name='$name'"
```

The problem is, this isn't very secure, as anything put in config.sh gets run:

```
$ ./script.sh
Malicious code!
After sourcing: verbose='yes', name='test'
```

To make it more secure, I thought I'd grep out assignment operations and only execute those. I would accomplish by passing `source` a "here document":

script.sh:

```
source <<EOF
$(grep -P '^\s*\w+=' test.sh)
EOF
echo "After sourcing: verbose='$verbose', name='$name'"
```

(Yes, I know the regex isn't that strong; it's just a placeholder.) Sadly, source doesn't seem to play well with here docs:

```
./script.sh: line 1: source: filename argument required
source: usage: source filename [arguments]
After sourcing: verbose='', name=''
```

Obviously I could do any number of things to get config data from a file, and that's likely more secure anyways.

But I'm still left with this itch; I want to figure out if what I've tried can work. Any suggestions?

Comment: In case this isn't clear from the answers, your problem is that a "here document" (`<<EOF`) acts like an ordinary input redirection (`< file`), and `source < file` doesn't work -- `source` needs to have a filename argument. Therefore, you need process substitution (`<(command)`), which looks like a filename argument.

Comment: An approach that's easy to make visibly safe: `while IFS== read -r var value; do case $var in |*[!0-9A-Z_a-z]*) complain;; *) eval "config_$var=\$value";; esac; done <config` (warning: typed in my browser, **test it!**) Don't forget not to allow importing variables like `PATH`, `IFS`, … A prefix like `config_` is a safe approach.

Comment: +1 Although [external control of configuration files](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/15.html) in itself may be a symptom of more serious security issues that input validation alone is not sufficient to address. This, however, would have other uses as well apart from the security aspects.

Comment: @G-Man - you dont need *process substitution* - which differs from a standard pipe mainly in that rather than passing data to a process's stdin it hands a process a link to its stdout as an argument, generally in the form `/dev/fd/[num]`. Emulating this is simple: `3<<HEREDOC . /dev/fd/3\n*file contents*\nHEREDOC\n`. Process substitution usually *is* a pipe, whereas heredocs are usually tmpfiles the shell deletes before handing them off - so they only exist as descriptors. in `dash` they are pipes. the other big difference is you can specify fd `[num]` for heredocs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`source` needs a filename, you can't redirect input to it.

On my system, I was able to use Process substitution instead:

```
source <( grep = test.sh )
```

Replace `=` with the appropriate regular expression.

Comment: heh, and here's the malicious code: `delete --recursively /this/important/dir #=`

Comment: @glennjackman: The `=` was just a placeholder.

Comment: Why not just give it a link to the descriptor? Thats all your process sub does anyway: `3<<HEREDOC . /dev/fd/3\nand so on...`

Comment: @mikeserv: Readability, maybe?

Comment: Seriously? You can of course call it whatever you want - and it is one of the few types of shell structs that does not submit easily to `;` stuffing. Moreover, you get to explicitly name and number the descriptor which is not a thing i believe can be done w/ substitutions. You can also have leading tabs automatically stripped - and so the code can be pretty parsed - it doesnt look good in a comment because i have to slash\n and so on, but it has a lot more potential - and it is portable. If you dont like `.dot` you should alias it - it is safer than `source` usually.

Comment: @mikeserv: In this particular case, the contents of the heredoc is just the command to filter another file.

Answer (score 9):

```
source <(cat << EOF
A=42
EOF
)
echo $A
```

Output:

```
42
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly `eval` it:

```
eval "$(grep -P '^\s*\w+=' config.sh)" 
#quotes needed if you want the full content of the file (including newlines etc.)
```

Sourcing is essentially the same as:

```
eval "$(cat file)"
```

Note, however, that people could be executing all kinz of codez at the right side of the equal sign:

```
a=$(evil_code_here)
b=`evil_code_here`
c="something" evil_code_here
#etc.
```

You need a better filter.